# How can I tell ConEmu to start every time when I open console from the Total Commander via Shift-Enter

Tags: conemu, total-commander

How can I tell ConEmu to start every time when I open console from the Total Commander via Shift-Enter? I've added "totalcmd64.exe" to the list of hooked executables in ConEmu but it works only when I start console via Enter, not Shift-Enter.

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift+Enter starts `noclose.exe` instead of `cmd.exe`. And noclose  is not a console subsystem process. So ConEmu does not hook it.

I think you need to configure your total to change what it is running.

BTW, ConEmu has internal "no close" feature:

```
cmd -new_console:c
```